# How to convert hash to array without the use of intermediate variable?

Tags: perl

How to convert hash to to array temporarily without using intermediate variable

For example in the following code "@arr" variable is an array storing the converted hash.

```
my %scientists = (
    "Newton"   => "Isaac",
    "Einstein" => "Albert",
    "Darwin"   => "Charles",
);

my @arr = %scientists;
print $_ . " " foreach @arr; # "Newton Isaac Darwin Charles Einstein Albert"
```

I am not trying to accomplish anything specific here. Just want to know if its possible to convert hash to an array wihtout intermediate variable

```
print ref(\@arr); # print array
```

similarly is there a something that can replace "" so that the following is possible

```
print ref(<syntax>%scientists%<sytax>) # should print array.
```

Comment: I think you are using the word Array when actually mean LIST. Arrays are variables with @sigil. LISTs are  sequences of values, normally separated by commas when noted literally.

Comment: [What’s the difference between a list and an array?](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/01/whats-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array/), since you mentioned it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In list context, `%hash` results in a key-value pairs of scalars.

For example, `%scientists` results in the six scalars `"Newton", "Isaac", "Einstein", "Albert", "Darwin", "Charles"`, although the order can vary.

This applies on the right-hand side of `my @arr =`.

```perl
my @arr = %scientists;
```

And it also applies for the list of a foreach loop.

```perl
print $_ . " " for %scientists;
```

Most of the time, however, one would use `keys( %scientists )` instead of just `%scientists`.

```perl
say "$_ $scientists{ $_ }" for keys( %scientists );
```

---

For the question at the bottom, you could use

```perl
say ref( [ %scientists ] );
```

`[ ... ]` is roughly equivalent to `do { my @anon = ...; \@anon }`.

In other words, it still creates an array, but the array is anonymous.

Answer (score 3):

The wording of the question seems inconsistent -- it is asking about an array, seemingly wanting a list in fact, but the discussion doesn't clearly support that either.  Perhaps it is a quest of how to "serialize" or stringify a hash, without creating variables. Here are some options

To print a hash I often use

```
say "$_ => $h{$_}" for keys %h;
```

or, so that it is always in the same order,

```
say "$_ => $h{$_}" for sort keys %h;
```

This approach can be used to build a list or a string of the key-value pairs.  For example

```
map { "$_ => $h{$_}" } keys %h;   # list of key-value strings
```

what can be further manipulated.  (With a hashref it's `keys %$hr` and `$h->{$_}` instead.)

Also, "dumper" libraries unpack data structures for us

```
use Data::Dump qw(pp);

my $fmt_str = pp \%h;  # formatted string. for formatted print use 'dd'
```

The package [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) need be installed. A core module, which should come installed with Perl, is [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) (function `Dumper` returns a formatted string).  There are yet others .

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the conversion to do?

If you want only the keys you can do

```
my @lastnames = keys %scientists;
```

If you want only the values you can do

```
my @firstnames = values %scientists;
```

If you want them intermingled as key/value pairs just do

```
my @names = %scientists;
```

The thing to remember is that since hashes are unordered, you don't know what order you will get back.

Comment: The question was how to avoid using an array, yet all of your snippets use an array.

Comment: The question said "How to convert hash to array without the use of intermediate variable?"

Comment: So why did you just copy the OP's code with a different variable name instead of removing the intermediate variable? They explicitly asked to remove the use of `@arr`, and all you did was rename it `@names`.

Comment: That's not correct.

Comment: Re "*That's not correct.*", OP's code is `my @arr = %scientists; ... foreach @arr;`. Your code is `my @names = %scientists;`. You just renamed the var. You did not eliminate it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a bit confusing (Array vs List), but I think what you really want is to convert a %Hash variable to a List in order to **dump** it, without intermediate @array variable.

Here a quick demo in the debugger:

> print ref(@arr); # print array

```
  DB<7> use Data::Dumper

  DB<8> print Dumper \%h
$VAR1 = {
          'Einstein' => 'Albert',
          'Darwin' => 'Charles',
          'Newton' => 'Isaac'
        };

  DB<9>
```

NB: [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) is core, i.e. available with every Perl version.

I personally prefer [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), which needs to be installed from CPAN.